# CGAffineTransform scaling and rotating

Tags: ios, rotation, scale, cgaffinetransform

I have an imageview that I am scaling and rotating via UISliders. Here is how I do so:

```
- (IBAction)sizeSlider:(UISlider *)sender
{
    int SCALE_MAX = 200;
    int SCALE_MIN = 10;
    CGAffineTransform transform = image.transform;
    float scale = sqrt(transform.a*transform.a + transform.c*transform.c);
    if (scale > SCALE_MAX)
        image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, SCALE_MAX/scale*sender.value, SCALE_MAX/scale*sender.value);
    else if (scale < SCALE_MIN)
        image.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, SCALE_MIN/scale*sender.value, SCALE_MIN/scale*sender.value);
}

- (IBAction)angleSlider:(UISlider *)sender
{  
    CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(sender.value);
        image.transform = t;
}
```

This works, however if the imageview has been scaled from its original size then rotating the image resets it to its original size. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the similar approach of your scale in your rotation. Meaning, use:

```
CGAffineTransformRotate(image.transform, theAngle);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGAffineTransformMakeRotation
```

creates a new transform based on identity. Scaling is part of a transform--you want to use

```
CGAffineTransformRotate
```

instead which adds rotation to the existing, scaled transform.